# Getting the dreaded module not instantiated error, but everything appears right

Tags: angularjs, module, controller

I'm getting the error: "[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: ReferenceError: isUndefined is not defined".    It suggests I misspelled something or forgot to included dependencies. I've checked and all my scripts are included, all my spelling is correct, and I don't think I've left any dependencies out.  I've got a lot of other controllers structured very similarly to this one with no problem, but now two of my most recent added controllers/views are giving me the error.  I stripped out all the logic to make sure I wasn't doing something inadvertent, but still no dice.  I'm including the module it says is undefined, a similar controller that works, and the controller (now stripped of all logic except a console.log) for the new view that doesn't work.  Any ideas?

The "undefined" module (with a number of logic taken out for brevity):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", 'ngAnimate', 'angular-growl', 'ui.select', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker']);

var HeaderCtl = function($scope, $location) {

    console.log('inside HeaderCtl : ' + $scope.isLoggedIn);
    $scope.tabSelected = function(tabname) {

        console.log('Server Parameter :' + $scope.tabname);
        $location.path("/" + $scope.tabname);
    }
}
```

app.controller("HeaderCtl", ["$scope", "$location", 'growl', HeaderCtl]);

The similar working controller based on the module:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module("myApp");

var loginController = function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, myApp, growl) {

    // $scope.currenttab = $scope.isLoggedIn;

    $scope.sendDt = function() {

        $http.post('/login', {
                username: $scope.user.username,
                password: $scope.user.password,
            })
            .success(function(user) {

                    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = 'yes';

                    console.log('successfully logged in and redirecting to :');

                    $location.path("/");

                    $http.get('/getnavlist').success(function(list) {
                        if (list !== '0') { // got some menus
                            $rootScope.navlist = list;
                            $location.path("/" + list[0].value);
                        }
                    });
                },
                function() {

                    console.log('error in logging in');
                    $rootScope.message = 'user name or password is wrong';

                    $location.path("#/welcomeLogin");
                });
    }

};

  app.controller("loginController", loginController);

}());
```

Finally, the error module with logic stripped out:

```
(function() {

var app = angular.module("myApp");

var signUpController = function($scope) {

    $scope.formModel = {};


    console.log("Woomp!");
}

app.controller("signUpController", signUpController);
```

}());

Comment: Is the file being minified? If so, the last one is throwing an error because you need to inject the objects with an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject angular `module` as injectable inside factory function. In `loginController` you had injected `myApp`(module name) as a dependency. This is root cause of your problem.

Change

```
                                                                   //VVVVV//remove this
var loginController = function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, myApp, growl) {
```

to

```
var loginController = function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location, growl) {
```

Comment: Hmmm. The login controller is working fine though.  You're saying that binds it there and will make it fine for that controller but mess up the later ones?

Comment: It may possible that minification is hurting since you're not following any DI injection anotation..